# Pull google spreadsheets data into solidity contract

Tags: solidity

How to pull google spreadsheets data to solidity contract? Say, to pay a given amount of money to given address - both things pulled from google spreadsheets

Answer (score 0):

You can make an asynchronous update using the [oracle](https://medium.com/@teexofficial/what-are-oracles-smart-contracts-the-oracle-problem-911f16821b53) pattern. Synchronous is currently not possible - there's no "wait for promise to resolve".

1. Create an off-chain app (the oracle) that listens to transactions from your contract to a specific address.
2. Each transaction (from your contract to the target address) will trigger an action in the off-chain app - e.g. reading the spreadsheet.
3. The oracle then sends another transaction to your smart contract, passing it the off-chain data - e.g. the address and amount. Your contract can be developed to accept this callback transaction only from a whitelisted address. After it accepts the data, it can perform the transaction.